# What is the proper way to define a bean that holds a list of objects created from a map in Spring

Tags: java, spring

I want to create a bean that takes a list of objects as an argument. The objects are created from a map.

The class definition is as follows:

```
@Data
public MyClass {
   private final List<MyObject>;
}

@Data
public class MyObject {
   private final String key; 
   private final String value;
   // Each MyObject will be created by one of the key-value pair 
   // defined in metricMap. 
}
```

Spring configuration file:

```
<bean id="myClass" class="com.example.MyClass">
   <constructor-arg name="objList" ref="objList"/>
</bean>

<util:map id="metricMap" map-class="java.util.HashMap">
  <entry key="key1" value="value1" />
  <entry key="key2" value="value2" />
  <entry key="key3" value="value3" />
</util:map>

<bean id="objList" class="com.example.ObjList"> 
  <constructor-arg name="metrics" ref="metricMap" />
</bean>
```

What is the recommended approach to accomplish this? Thanks.

Comment: this xml file is mal-formed. you should always include well-formed files and classes that compile when asking a question.

Comment: Fixed the typo in the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i'm not sure i understand the question but this works:

```
public class ObjectList {

    private List<MyObject> myObjects = new ArrayList<>();

    public ObjectList(Map<String, Object> metrics) {
        metrics.entrySet().forEach(metric -> {
            MyObject myObject = new MyObject(metric.getKey(), metric.getValue());
            myObjects.add(myObject);
        });
    }
}

@Data
public class MyClass {
    private final List<MyObject> objectList;

    public MyClass(List<MyObject> objectList) {
        this.objectList = objectList;
    }
}

@Data
public class MyObject {
    private final String key;
    private final Object value;

    public MyObject(String key, Object value) {
        this.key = key;
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

and the bean defs:

```
<bean id="myClass" class="com.example.MyClass">
   <constructor-arg name="objectList" ref="objectList"/>
</bean>

<util:map id="metricMap" map-class="java.util.HashMap">
  <entry key="key1" value="value1" />
  <entry key="key2" value="value2" />
  <entry key="key3" value="value3" />
</util:map>

<bean id="objectList" class="com.example.ObjectList"> 
  <constructor-arg name="metrics" ref="metricMap"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: Thanks. I see your point. Just to clarify, in MyClass the access to myObjects attribute is via getter method, right? i.e., objectList.getMyObject()

Comment: you can add getter methods. i still don't understand your question or the confusion. i added getters to this and made it into a tiny app and all the metrics printed out. this works for me. i don't know why it wouldn't work for you.

Comment: the idea is not for us to code every line of code for you. it's to point you in the right direction and help you get unstuck.

Comment: I didn't say it didn't work for me. I am new to Spring and just wanted to understand the best approach to do that. Thanks

Comment: no worries. i wasn't sure i understood the question. didn't mean to come across as snarky. tone on the internet can be ambiguous.